# How to add a css class to postTitleWrapper in Gutenberg?

Tags: javascript, block-editor

while working with react/JS is slowly getting easier, at times I'm still surprised why things don't work as I expect them to. Here, I'm trying to add a class to the '.edit-post-visual-editor__post-title-wrapper'-div and I'm using the below code in a JS file that is apparently correctly enqueued. When I inspect the page I see the element, it contains the post title. Yet somehow the console always tells me postTitleWrapper is null.
What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for any help!

```
wp.domReady(function() {
    const postTitleWrapper = document.querySelector('.edit-post-visual-editor__post-title-wrapper');
    console.log(postTitleWrapper);
    if (postTitleWrapper) {
        postTitleWrapper.classList.add('something');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably related to how you're loading that JS file, which causes it to run before the element is available (despite `domReady`).

You didn't show how you're loading the file etc, but your code works for me in a standard Gutenberg block `edit.js`:

```
export default function Edit() {
    domReady( function () {
        const postTitleWrapper = document.querySelector(
            '.edit-post-visual-editor__post-title-wrapper'
        );

        console.log( postTitleWrapper );

        if ( postTitleWrapper ) {
            postTitleWrapper.classList.add( 'something' );
        }
    } );

    return (
        <div>
            hello world
        </div>
    );
}
```

It also works in a Gutenberg plugin like this:

#### php

```
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'enqueue_my_script' );

function enqueue_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'postTitleWrapperClass',
        trailingslashit( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ) . 'post-title-wrapper-class.js',
        array( 'wp-dom' ),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'post-title-wrapper-class.js' ),
        true
    );
}
```

#### js

```
const PostTitleClassWrapper = () => {
    wp.domReady(function() {
        const postTitleWrapper = document.querySelector('.edit-post-visual-editor__post-title-wrapper');

        console.log(postTitleWrapper);

        if (postTitleWrapper) {
            postTitleWrapper.classList.add('something');
        }
    });
};

wp.plugins.registerPlugin( 'post-title-class-wrapper', {
    render: PostTitleClassWrapper,
    icon: null,
} );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive answer! Will try your code asap. Below is the code I'm currently using to enqueue the script. My dependency array included "wp-dom-ready", is "wp-dom-ready" wrong? I think I got it from here: [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-styles/)

`add_action(
 'enqueue_block_editor_assets',
 function() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
   'my_gutenberg-plugin',
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/build/editor.js',
   array( 'wp-dom-ready' ),
   false,
   false
  );
 }
);
`

Comment: Thanks again, I restructured my plugin based on your code and it works, even though I'm still not entirel sure about why it didn't work before.